# “Gradeaus” vs. “geradeaus”

Tags: usage, spelling

I know that

> geradeaus

means *straight.* But I also heard its variation:

> gradeaus

Is it appropriate to say or write this word like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its meaning is the same.

> Gradeaus

is a kind of idiom. The written word is always

> Geradeaus

both words are translated to *straight*.

Comment: Are you sure that you mean "idiom"?

Comment: Slang / Jargon trifft es nicht ganz, da es doch ziemlich weit verbreitet ist (zumindest im Süden Deutschlands). Es ist eher ein Wort welches ich den Dialekten zuordnen würde daher "idiom" (http://www.dict.cc/?s=idiom)

Comment: Das ist kein Idiom, da kein anderes Wort, ein unbetontes "e" wird in vielen Dialekten einfach weggelassen.

Answer (score 5):

"Gradeaus" is a **contraction** for "geradeaus."

Think of geradeaus spelled with an apostrophe instead of the first e: g'radeaus.

Comment: where I am from (Swabia) we even further contract it to  *gradaus* ;)

Comment: @Takkat: Good to know. Is Swabia the home of "Auf der Schwaebscher Eisenbahn"?

Comment: it is: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auf_de_Schw%C3%A4b%E2%80%99sche_Eisenbahne ;)

Answer (score 1):

In spoken language unstressed e often is omitted. You can hear gerade, grade and grad. It's all the same. But you write gerade.

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on the location you are in. In South Germany, they say *gradeaus,* but in the north, they say *greadeaus.*

Comment: Do you have any evidence for your claim? Maybe a map? Additionally google says: gradeaus is a non-correct spelling...

Comment: Did you really want to write *greadeaus* instead of *geradeaus?* (I did not correct it, because it might be intended.)